# How do I create an MVC API action that takes two parameters

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to create an MVC API interfaces that uses part of the URL and the form post values. I really need to have a value/varible in the url that will act as a variable that I will do some magic with so the use of {code} variable.

Form Action:

/api/ordermanager/orderretrival/89-78/    (Pattern:api/{controller}/{action}/{code}/

```
       <form action="/api/ordermanager/orderretrival/89-78/" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" >
         <input type="hidden" name="function" id="function" value="sendversion" />
         <input type="hidden" name="omversion" id="omversion" value="7.004" />
         This will get the version number for you.
         <input type="submit" value="Get Version"/>
       </form>
```

I created this MapHttpRoute

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "OrderManager",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{code}",
            defaults: new { code = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I created this action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("OrderRetrival")]
    public string OrderRetrieval(string code, NameValueCollection formData)
    {
        return formData["omversion"].ToString() ;
    }
```

But the formData is blank (I wish there was a little more explaining how stuff gets into the parameters).

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you use the post from your client code, but assuming you are posting the second parameter this might help:

```
public string OrderRetrieval(string code, [FromBody] NameValueCollection formData)
```

note the `FromBody` attribute

Comment: I added the FromBody but I am still seeing an empty NameValueCollection.  Any Ideas?

Comment: post your client side code where you are making the call please